# Dynamic phone based on Sender

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Our footer currently pulls in the address using personalization strings

```
%%Member_Addr%%
%%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%% %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%
```

but then underneath that, we have our phone number
555-555-5555 and web address
website@domain.com

Is there a way to dynamically pull in the phone number based on the email address in the sender profile? We want to make sure that each department has their phone number represented.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can do is follow Leto's answer but create just one generic Delivery Profile or alter the one you currently use and use variables for the email address and phone number using AMPScript.

Assuming you use Data Extensions you can then include the correct email address and phone number in that Data Extension with the email send.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to configure a Delivery Profile for every departament.

If you do in the way you are saying, you need to select the Sender Profile at sending time after coded something (I don't know if it's possible to do in this way you want) to get the Sender and set the phone number in your email footer.

Since you already have to select the Sender Profile, you could also select the Delivery Profile with the correct Phone Number in send set up.

Go to Classic Content in Email Studio -> Content

[image]

Create a Content (could be free form) with your desired footer, with the phone number (for every phone number, or sender in this case, you need to create one footer)

[image]

Then go to Email Studio -> Admin -> Send Management -> Delivery Profiles. Create a new one for every footer, and select the footers you have created before.

[image]

And when you are setting up sends you can select the Delivery Profile.

[image]